# How do I make a second order differential equation match a difference equation?

Tags: differential-equations, difference-equations

I have fitted a difference equation to some data and would now like to find a differential equation that matches the difference equation. The difference equation and differential equation are

$$
y(n)=f(n) y(n-k)+g(n) y(n-2 k)
$$
$$
y''(t)+p(t) y'(t)+q(t) y(t)=0
$$
These are linear  difference and differential equations with variable coefficients. f[n] and g[n] are cubic interpolation functions and I would like p[t] and q[t] to also be interpolation functions.

Mathematica can solve symbolic difference equations and differential equations with cubic variable coefficients. Thus

```
ClearAll[y, f0, f1, f2, f3, g0, g1, g2, g3, n, p0, p1, p2, p3, q0, q1,
   q2, q3, t];
RSolve[y[n] == (f0 + f1 n + f2 n^2 + f3 n^3) y[
     n - 5] + (g0 + g1 n + g2 n^2 + g3 n^3) y[n - 10], y[n], n]
DSolve[y''[t] + (p0 + p1 t + p2 t^2 + p3 t^3) y'[
     t] + (q0 + q1 t + q2 t^2 + q3 t^3) y[t] == 0, y[t], t]
```

[image]

[image]

The output is in terms of DifferenceRoot and DifferentialRoot  respectively.

For difference and differential equations with constant coefficients the solutions are just

```
RSolve[y[n] == f0 y[n - k] + g0 y[n - 2 k], y[n], n]
DSolve[y''[t] + p0 y'[t] + q0 y[t] == 0, y[t], t]
```

[image]

[image]

So knowing the solution to the difference equation enables the coefficients of the differential equation to be found by simple matching (also time  t = (n-1) dt where dt is the sampling increment)  how do I do this for my variable coefficients?

Here is some fitted data.
[image]

The vertical lines are the locations of knots in the fitting data. One interval of my difference equation  is given by

```
k = 5; (* Backward step increment *)
t1 = 0.07894736842105263`; (* Starting time *)
dt = 0.0004`; (* Time increment *)
dd = {-0.9573507176866912`, -2.024394628072429`, -3.0177598379156`, \
-3.902923724734958`, -4.648984716450747`, -5.22977777434798`, \
-5.624836149234829`, -5.820162645659958`, -5.808779618675913`, \
-5.591034714271433`, -5.174647219824499`}; (* Initial conditions data \
*)
(* Variable coefficients data *)
f = Function[{t}, 
  1.8268003676664075` - 8.64235779514729` t - 
   5.046775951053236` t^2 + 104.88522863362422` t^3];
g = Function[{t}, -1.0031787122707823` + 0.3806275165536718` t - 
    1.0674501046346905` t^2 + 0.7316362694127528` t^3];
ClearAll[y];
ic = Table[y[n] == dd[[n]], {n, 1, 10}];
op = RecurrenceTable[
   Join[{y[n] == 
      f[t1 + (n - 1) dt] y[n - 5] + g[t1 + (n - 1) dt] y[n - 10]}, 
    ic], y[n], {n, 1, 67}];


ListPlot[op, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

How can I get a differential equation with variable coefficients that matches this difference equation? If I can do each interval in the interpolation function in turn as a piecewise function then I have a solution. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing ideas for the case with $k = 1$ the correspondence between

$$
\cases{
y(n)=f(n) y(n-k)+g(n) y(n-2 k)\\
y''(t)+p(t) y'(t)+q(t) y(t)=0
}
$$

can be obtained as a limit. The cases with $k>1$ would require higher order analogies. So following with $k = 1$ and considering the differential operator approximation $\dot y \approx \frac{y(t+dT)-y(t)}{dT}$ we have

$$
\ddot y + p\dot y+q y \approx \frac{y(t_k)-2y(t_k-dT)+y(t_k-2dT)}{dT^2}+p(t_k)\frac{y(t_k)-y(t_k-dT)}{dT}+q(t_k)y(t_k)
$$

then making $j=\frac{t_k}{dT}$ and calling $Y(j) = y(j dT)$ we get the relationship

$$
\ddot y + p\dot y+q y \approx \frac{Y(j)-2Y(j-1)+Y(j-2)}{dT^2}+P(j)\frac{Y(j)-Y(j-1)}{dT}+Q(j)Y(j)
$$

and also

$$
\lim_{dT\to 0}\left(\frac{Y(j)-2Y(j-1)+Y(j-2)}{dT^2}+P(j)\frac{Y(j)-Y(j-1)}{dT}+Q(j)Y(j)\right) = \ddot y + p\dot y+q y
$$

Now considering the code

```
Clear["Global`*"]
p[t_] := p0 + p1 t + 0 p2 t^2 + 0 p3 t^3
q[t_] := q0 + q1 t + 0 q2 t^2 + 0 q3 t^3
parms = {p0 -> 1, p1 -> 1, p2 -> 0, p3 -> 0, q0 -> 0, q1 -> 1, q2 -> 1, q3 -> 0, dT -> 1/4}
tmax = 4;
soly = DSolve[y''[t] + p[t] y'[t] + q[t] y[t] == 0, y[t], t][[1]] /. parms // Simplify;
yt = y[t] /. soly;
cond1 = (yt /. {t -> 0}) - 1;
cond2 = (yt /. {t -> tmax});
solC = Solve[{cond1 == 0, cond2 == 0}, {C[1], C[2]}][[1]];
yt0 = yt /. solC;
gr1 = Plot[yt0, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All];

equdY = (1 + dT (p0 + dT k p1 + dT (q0 + dT k q1))) Y[k] + Y[k - 2] - (2 + dT (p0 + dT k p1)) Y[k - 1] /. parms;
solY = RSolve[equdY == 0, Y, k][[1]] ;
Ynu = Y[nu] /. solY;
nu0 = Ceiling[tmax/dT /. parms];
cond1 = (Ynu /. {nu -> 0}) - 1;
cond2 = (Ynu /. {nu -> nu0});
solC = Solve[{cond1 == 0, cond2 == 0}, {C[1], C[2]}][[1]];
Ynu0 = Ynu /. solC;
Yk = Table[{nu (dT /. parms), Ynu0}, {nu, 0, nu0}];
gr2 = ListPlot[Yk, PlotStyle -> Red]
Show[gr1, gr2]
```

[image]

we can corroborate those ideas.

NOTE

We condidered that only the cases involving

```
p[t_] := p0 + p1 t 
q[t_] := q0 + q1 t
```

could be used due to the existence of solutions in closed form.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is along the lines of Euler's approach.  Direct approximation of the differential equation as a difference equation.  This is a very reasonable idea. I was hoping that the exact solutions available using holonomic functions could be used somehow but thanks anyway.